# Android limit edittext length

Tags: android, input, android-edittext

I am having problem with limiting edittext length in android. Everything works perfect except when delete message.
My edit text control has max length of 16 characters and it will limit it for recognizing, displaying  and reading first 16 characters but when I continue to type, it memorizes text somewhere in background and if I want to delete text it doesn't start to delete backwards from 16th character but from last one I have entered.
See below code.

I have even tried to add TextChangedListener it doesn't trigger 16 character is entered as there isn't any action.

I am using Nexus 7 for testing this functionality

LAYOUT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/send_new_message_lblTo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/send_new_message_to"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/send_new_message_lblToValue"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/send_new_message_lblTo"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" >
    </TextView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/send_new_message_txtMessage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/send_new_message_lblToValue"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/send_new_message_hint"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="2"
        android:maxLength="16"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/send_new_message_btnSend"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/send_new_message_txtMessage"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/send" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

ACTIVITY

```
  import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.text.Editable;
    import android.text.TextWatcher;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class NewMessageSendActivity{

    private TextView to;
    private EditText message;
    private Button send;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.send_message);
        getViewInstances();
        setControlActions();

    }

    private void getViewInstances() {
        to = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.send_new_message_lblToValue);
        message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.send_new_message_txtMessage);
        send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_new_message_btnSend);

        to.setText(AppSettings.getInstance().getSelectedDevice().toString());
    }

    private void setControlActions() {

        send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                String smsMessage = message.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(this, smsMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: try this: http://androidblogger.blogspot.in/2009/01/numeric-edittext-and-edittext-with-max.html

Comment: Why do you specify a 2-lines `EditText` for only 16 characters?

Comment: @Raffaele 2-lines EditText was specified some time before and it stayed that way, nevertheless I have set it to 1 line and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your behavior. It seems everything is ok, and the text is correctly limited to 16 characters.

The only place where the keyboard keeps appending text, is in the field above it, but even when you select the suggested word, it is truncated before being inserted in the text field. That's why you don't see the event fired, because it's an internal event in the IME, not an Android one inside the `EditText`.

Comment: Try in following way, type word with more than 16 characters and after that start to delete with backspace, id doesn't delete 16th character it starts to delete from last entered character. (If you or anyone else understood what I just wrote :) )

Comment: I have just tried this on some older Samsung Android 2.3 versio, and it work as it supposed to. Maybe it is behaves this vay only on new version of android because I am testing it on Nexus 7 updated to latest version

Comment: @Damir All I can see is the virtual keyboard keeps updating its suggestion even beyond the 16th character, so the backspace works on the suggestion and the resulting text is obviously not mirrored in the `TextView`.  But this happens because the virtual keyboard has that suggestion feature, it has nothing to do with the app side, it's all internal to the IME

Comment: Thank you very much for explanation, I hope client will accept it :)